# Special kind of translation and rotational invariance of the numerical range

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

> Let $T\in\mathscr{B(\mathcal{H})}$ and $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is the following statement true?
>   If $W(B\otimes X)\subseteq W(B\otimes T)$ for any $B\in M_n$ then $W(B\otimes (X+I_n))\subseteq W(B\otimes (T+I))$ for any $B\in M_n$ where $W(T):=\{\langle Tx,x\rangle: \Vert x\Vert=1\}$ is called the numerical range of $T$.

---

**Comments:** I have tried this in various ways. I have observed yet that if $W(T)$ be a straight line (both degenerate and nondegenerate case) or $W(T)$ contains a neighbourhood around $0$, the previous statement is true. But for other cases, I could neither yet prove the statement nor find a counterexample to disprove this. Any comment is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X=0$ and $T=-I$ is a counter example, but I wouldn't be surprised if you want to rule this out?

Comment: @JamieGabe, How does it provide a counter example? As $W(B\otimes X)\subseteq W(B\otimes T)$ should be true for any $B\in M_n$ but according to your example, this is true for those $B$ with $0\in W(B)$. In other words,  I wanted to check whether the following is true: $$\cap_{B\in M_n}\{X\in M_n: W(B\otimes X)\subseteq W(B\otimes T)\}\subseteq \cap_{B\in M_n}\{X\in M_n: W(B\otimes (X+I))\subseteq W(B\otimes (T+I))\}.$$ ofcourse this is not true for a perticular choice of $B$.

Comment: @JamieGabe, Moreover if $T$ is normal then the statement is true as $W(A\otimes B)=\text{ Conv }W(A)W(B)$ whenever at least one of $A$ and $B$ is normal.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, it's definitely not a counterexample. My bad!

Comment: @JamieGabe, I think your example serves as a counterexample because of the following. Note that $W(B\otimes X)\subseteq W(B\otimes T)$ for any $B$ is equivalent with $W((\alpha B+\beta)\otimes X)\subseteq W((\alpha B+\beta)\otimes T)$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}, B\in M_n$ which allows us to take $0\in W(B)$ without loss of generality and then your example provides a counterexample. Is this argument correct? I apologize for making the statement that it is true for normal $T$ as I have realized now that the proof what I was thinking is not correct.

Comment: @JamieGabe If you take $T=-I$ then as $W(B\otimes X)\subseteq W(B\otimes T)$ for all $B\in M_n$, in particular we have $W(X)\subseteq W(T)=\{-1\}$ which implies $X=-I_n$. So one can not take $X=0$. I am really now very much confused. As I have written in the comment that it is true for all $T$ with $W(T)$ is either a straight line or contains a neighborhood around $0$, counterexample should come (in case if it be not true) from other left cases.